# Storing a graph in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, graph, database

I have an undirected graph where each node contains an array. Data can be added/deleted from the array. What's the best way to store this in Mongodb and be able to do this query effectively: given node A, select all the data contained in the adjacent nodes of A.

In relational DB, you can create a table representing the edges and another table for storing the data in each node this so.

```
table 1 
NodeA, NodeB
NodeA, NodeC

table 2 
NodeA, item1
NodeA, item2
NodeB, item3
```

And then you join the tables when you query for the data in adjacent nodes. But join is not possible in MongoDB, so what's the best way to setup this database and efficiently query for data in adjacent nodes (favoring performance slightly over space).

Comment: Two queries, one to get the list of adjacent nodes and one to get the data in those nodes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm picking up mongo, looking into this sort of schema as well (undirected graphs, querying  for information from neighbors)  I think the way that I favor so far looks something like this:

Each node contains an array of neighbor keys, like so.

```
{
 nodeIndex: 4
 myData: "data"
 neighbors: [8,15,16,23,42]
}
```

To find data from neighbors, use the [$in "operator"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#_S_in):

```
db.nodes.find({nodeIndex:{$in: [8,15,16,23,42]}});
```

You can use [field selection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-FieldSelection) to limit results to the relevant data.

```
db.nodes.find({nodeIndex:{$in: [8,15,16,23,42]}}, {myData:1});
```

Comment: MongoDB also provides a few other operators that will come in handy for modifying this data: `$push` or `$addToSet` for creating new edges between nodes, and `$pull` for removing edges. All are documented [on the updating page of the MongoDB docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating) You'll want to be careful to always update nodes at both ends of an edge.

Comment: What happens if I have many nodes (million like Twitter graph), MongoDB documents are limited to 16MB. Is there any solution to this limit?

Comment: I'm no MongoDB expert, but I think that's a limit on the document, not the collection or the database. In this schema, 1 document == 1 node. So the issue is how dense or sparse your graph is, not the raw number of nodes.

Comment: @Zopa is correct, the 16MB limit is by document http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-types-in-mongodb

Comment: Another limitation of MongoDB is the size of the array. This schema will fall apart as the number of neighbors increases. My personal experience says this is about 100 elements before performance starts to degrade to an unreasonable amount. Indexed arrays have additional overhead to consider if your database is doing a lot of writes.

Answer (score 25):

### Specialized Distributed Graph Databases

I know this is sounds a little far afield from the OPs question about Mongo, but these days there are more specialized graph databases that excel at this kind of work and may be much easier for you to use, especially on large graphs.

There is a comparison of 7 such offerings here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlHPKx74VyC5dERyMHlLQ2lMY3dFQS1JRExYQUNhdVE#gid=0

Of the three most significant open source offerings (Titan, OrientDB, and Neo4J), all of them support the Tinkerpop Blueprints interface.  So for a graph that looks like this...

[image]

... a query for "all the people that Juno greatly admires who she has known since the year 2011" would look like this:

```
Iterable<Vertex> results = juno.query().labels("knows").has("since",2011).has("stars",5).vertices()
```

This, of course, is just the tip of the iceberg.  Pretty powerful stuff!

### If you have to stay with Mongo

Think of Tinkerpop Blueprints as the "JDBC of storing graph structures" in various databases.  The Tinkerpop Blueprints API has a specific MongoDB implementation that would work for you I'm sure.  Then using Tinkerpop Gremlin, you have all sorts of advanced traversal and search methods at your disposal.

Comment: About the list comparing graph persistence.. Gemstone could be a good addition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemstone_(database)

Comment: Titan is not a true graph. Neo4J and OriendDB do not scale horizontally.

Comment: How is it not a true graph?

Answer (score 9):

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB for inspiration.

Comment: Trees are subgraphs. This may be helpful in thinking of ways to structure graph indexes.

Answer (score 5):

*MongoDB* will introduce native graph capabilities in *version 3.4* and it could be used to store graph stuctures and do analytics on them although performance might not be that good compared to native graph databases like *Neo4j* depending on the cases but it is too early to judge.

Check those links for more information:

- [$graphLookup (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)
- [MongoDB 3.4 Accelerates Digital Transformation for the Modern Enterprise](https://www.mongodb.com/press/3_4)

Comment: It is (for now) probably not as good as Neo4j given that it does not work on sharded collections for example.

Comment: MongoDB site has a nice webinar: [Working with Graph Data in MongoDB 3.4](https://resources.mongodb.com/vidyard-all-players-13/webinar-working-with-graph-data-in-mongodb-3-4-9)

Comment: Adding one more modern article about storing graph in MongoDN: https://www.mongodb.com/databases/mongodb-graph-database

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB can simulate a graph using a flexible tree hierarchy. You may want to consider neo4j for strict graphing needs.